# validate search result using Linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a search result from the database,

```
int searchTerm = "xx"

var result = from orderLines in context.OrderLineSearch(searchTerm)
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        OrderNumber = orders.OrderNumber,
                                        OrderLineId = orders.OrderLineId
                                    };
```

I need to validate whether result contains many orders. That is I need to check whether multiple orders are returned or not.

I did the validation by storing the first order number in a variable and compared whether all the other rows contains only this order number. See below

```
string orderNumber = result.First().OrderNumber;

bool isValid = result.Where(x => x.OrderNumber != orderNumber).Count() == 0;
```

I want to know the best way to validate using LINQ? Can any one help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not what it means to validate something...

Comment: Hmmm yep.. 'Check' might be a right word then i guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should to try group results by OrderNumber and then calculate Count?

```
var result = from orderLines in context.OrderLineSearch(searchTerm)
             group orderLines by orderLines.OrderNumber into g   
             select g.Key     
bool hasElements = result.Any();
```

Comment: You should always use `result.Any()` instead of `result.Count() == 0`. The former breaks as soon as one result is hit, the latter has to enumerate all results.